# Change directory including username in shell script

Tags: shell

I'm trying to change directory in shell script. I used to do this:

```
cd /Users/usera/data/
```

but now I want to change directory and include the username automatically. Following this [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bsd-shell-script-get-current-user/), I used this:

```
myuser="$(id -u -n)"
cd /Users/"$myuser"/data/
```

but this doesn't work and considers it as `cd /Users/` only

Comment: Run the script with `-x` and post the output of this part of the script.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `cd /Users/"$USER"/data/`. As suggested by David, If you want to use `$(id -u -n)` then you need `#!/bin/sh` at the top of your script.

Comment: No need, see @M.llie's answer. I suspect you need a `#!/bin/sh` at the top of your script (and you need to insure the file is executable, e.g. `chmod 0755 filename`), or you need to run it with `sh myscript`. There is nothing wrong with your use of *command substitution* (e.g. `myuser="$(id -u -n)"`) and `cd /Users/"$myuser"/data/` is correct, but you will generally see `cd "/Users/$myuser/data/"`.

Comment: To add to David's comment: Using `$USER` is the simplest and most efficient solution, but there's no reason `$(id -u -n)` shouldn't work in a POSIX-like shell.

Comment: Perhaps the more helpful information would be: (a) _how you invoked_ your script while it had no [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (`#!/bin/sh`), and (b) what the exact failure symptom was (error message) - add the latter to your _question_, please.

Answer (score -1):

On my computer,this command runs fine.
Maybe you can change your command like this:

```
myuser="$(id -u -n)"
cd /Users/"${myuser}"/data/
```

or

```
myuser=`id -u -n`
cd /Users/"${myuser}"/data/
```

Comment: If the assumption is that a POSIX-like shell is being used, this won't make a difference (except that `\`...\`` is obsolescent). If you think that a different shell is being used, state that assumption.

Comment: @mklement0 : It is correct that the question doesn't make much sense, unless we know what shell we are talking about, **but** if the shell would not understand `$(....)` , the script would have aborted or at least issued an error message.

Comment: @user1934428: `csh` would fall into that category, but the assignment wouldn't work without `set`. Yes, you can view this as a vague recommendation for troubleshooting, but something like that belongs in a _comment_ rather than an answer.

Comment: Yes, well .... it's a comment after all, isn't it? As for the OPs question: I don't think we can see what's going on, unless we get more information. The excerpt the user posted looks fine to me. Maybe `id` is not /usr/bin/id, but a script or function which gets executed and does something completely different...

Comment: @user1934428: You must @-mention me to be notified of follow-up comments. By _comment_ I mean: using the _form_ of a comment _post_ as provided by this site, as opposed to an answer post. If the content is a comment in the colloquial sense, it should also have the _form_ of a comment; answer posts are for _solutions_. The OP has posted a solution themselves saying a shebang line fixed the problem, and I've encouraged them to tell us what the original problem was - without that, this whole page is of little benefit to future readers.